# how to add variable in array element in php?

Tags: php, arrays

**Code:**

```
public $img_config = array('thum_img' => array(
        'image_ratio_crop' => true,
        'image_resize' => true,
        'image_x' => 175,
        'image_y' => 240
    ),
    'small_img' => array(
        'image_ratio_crop' => true,
        'image_resize' => true,
        'image_x' => 110,
        'image_y' => 35
    ),
    'parent_dir' => 'productImages',
    'target_path' => array(
        'thum_img' => WWW_ROOT . 'productImages' . DS . 'thum' . DS,
        'small_img' => WWW_ROOT . 'productImages' . DS . 'small' . DS
    )
);
```

This does not work. `WWW_ROOT . 'productImages' . DS . 'thum' . DS, and  WWW_ROOT . 'productImages' . DS . 'small' . DS` is the reason of the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'

Comment: `WWW_ROOT` & `DS` are fine?

Comment: put  'WWW.ROOT '.'productImages' . 'DS' . like this and try

Comment: They must be constants. @User

Comment: What is `WWW_ROOT` and `DS`? Try use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.properties says:

> #### Properties
>
> [...]
>
> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, *but this initialization must be a constant value*--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

[Constant Scalar Expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs) were added [in php 5.6.0](http://docs.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0).
Therefore

```
<?php
define('A_CONSTANT', '123');
class Foo {
    public $bar = 'abc'.A_CONSTANT;
}
```

works in php 5.6+ but not before.